# ¿Cómo guardar los elementos de una array en un ciclo for?

Tags: python

Por alguna razón, este código de `python` no funciona, lo que quiero hacer es encontrar el numero de más a la derecha que sea menor que el último numero de una `array`.

```
seq = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
row = 0
bp = []


for i in reversed(seq):
    if i < seq[-1]:
        bp.append(i)

print(bp)
```

Por alguna razón, me imprime `[0]` y no `[0, 1, 1]`, que son los números que recorre el ciclo `for` hasta encontrar el número que es menor que el último. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Pero tu no tienes algún número que sea menor a 1 en tu secuencia ... :S

Comment: Tratando de adivinar el comportamiento esperado, no será <= (menor o igual)? En ese caso, todo número que sea menor o exactamente 1 se incluirá en la lista.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es ir agregando cada elemento que ha sido recorrido en la lista `bp` e interrumpir el ciclo `for` con `break` cuando encuentres un número menor al último número de tu lista `seq`.

Ejemplo:

```
seq = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
row = 0
bp = []

for i in reversed(seq):
    bp.append(i)
    if i < seq[-1]:
        break

print(bp)
```

Esto imprime:

```
[1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

vamos por partes, tu código imprime **[ 0, 0 ]**, ya que guardas en **bp** todos los números menores que el último, ahora bien, tu enunciado dice: "encontrar el número de más a la derecha que sea menor que el último número de una `array`", para lograr eso, tienes que recorrer el `array` normalmente, y en vez de agregar `item's` en una lista, inicializas una variable, algo así:

```
seq = [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]

def ultimoMenorQueUltimo( lista ):
    for i in lista:
        if i < lista[-1]:
            ultimoMenor = i 
    return ultimoMenor
    
print( ultimoMenorQueUltimo( seq ))
```

Esto imprime **[ 0 ]**.

Ahora, si lo que quieres imprimir es **[ 1, 1, 0 ]**, osea todos los números que se encuentran a la derecha del último número menor que el último del `array`, la respuesta de @HeytalePazguato, es la correcta.